# Update a displayed text in WooCommerce Checkout on shipping country change

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The following code works, displaying the country in which the shipment is to be delivered:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'message', 10 );
function message(){
    $zone = WC()->session->get('customer')['shipping_country'];

    if( $zone == "SK" ) // 
    {
        echo "$zone";  
    } else {
        echo "Other zone";  
    }
}
```

However, if the customer changes the address, text will not be updated in the woocommerce_before_checkout_form., i.e. the refresh will not work.

I tried other hooks, but none worked.

How to solve this problem? Doing a call via ajax somehow?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some changes in your code and some jQuery code as follows:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'checkout_delivery_zone_message', 10 );
function checkout_delivery_zone_message(){
    $zone         = WC()->session->get('customer')['shipping_country'];
    $countries    = WC()->countries->get_countries();
    $shop_zone    = 'SK';
    $is_shop_zone = $zone === $shop_zone;
    $display_none = ' style="display:none;"';

    printf('<div class="message-zone"><span class="sk"%s>%s</span><span class="other"%s>%s</span></div>', 
        $is_shop_zone ? '' : $display_none,
        $countries[$shop_zone] . __(" zone", "woocommerce"), 
        $is_shop_zone ? $display_none : '',
        __("Other zone", "woocommerce") );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_delivery_zone_message_js', 10 );
function checkout_delivery_zone_message_js() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', '[name=billing_country],[name=shipping_country]', function(){
            var countryCode = null;
            if( ( ! $('[name=ship_to_different_address]').prop('checked') && $(this).prop('id') === 'billing_country' ) || 
            ( $('[name=ship_to_different_address]').prop('checked') && $(this).prop('id') === 'shipping_country' ) ) {
                countryCode = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').val();
            }
            if ( countryCode !== null ) {
                if ( countryCode === 'SK' ) {
                    $('.message-zone .sk').show();
                    $('.message-zone .other').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.message-zone .other').show();
                    $('.message-zone .sk').hide();
                }
            }
        }).on('change', '[name=ship_to_different_address]', function(){
            var countryCode = null;
            if( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
                countryCode = $('[name=shipping_country] option').filter(':selected').val();
            } else {
                countryCode = $('[name=billing_country] option').filter(':selected').val();
            }
            if ( countryCode !== null ) {
                if ( countryCode === 'SK' ) {
                    $('.message-zone .sk').show();
                    $('.message-zone .other').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.message-zone .other').show();
                    $('.message-zone .sk').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.